# Is it possible to provide the user with status reports from Flask during a looping python function?

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

I'm working on a Flask python web app in pythonanywhere that takes a file upload and processes it. The processing can take several minutes as it iterates through each row of the dataframe. I'd like to show the user what row is being processed or at least when every x rows have been processed. I haven't been able to get either flash messages or rendering templates to work to show the status information. Is it possible to provide the user with the kind of status updates I am looking for?

Comment: It's a good question, but I don't think you'll find the answer you're looking for in Flask.  In fact, even the Flask docs recommend using jquery to achieve this kind of thing (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/#an-easier-solution) instead of doing some sort of polling of where the file uploading is.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm not sure jquery would work for something like this because the info that needs to be shown in the update is where in the python loop the program is, which I think is something that the python code would have to provide and not something that could be queried.